# Interfaz sincronizacion

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola como puedo hacer una conexion de inicio de sesion a mi interfaz, 
O sea como que mi interfaz este conectada por ejemplo a gmail

Comment: A que te refieres al decir: *O sea como que mi interfaz este conectada por ejemplo a gmai*?, esa no es una explicación nada clara, ademas django que tiene que ver con tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es un login de entrada a tu aplicación, si el usuario y la contraseña son correctos accedes al programa, si no, no se ejecuta. Los usuarios los puedes almacenar en una base de datos, en un archivo de tu aplicación o dentro del mismo programa. Creo que te refieres a algo de esto.